# Увеличение числа выше предела переменной

Tags: c#, c++

если в с++/с# к переменной размером (например) в 1 байт и значением 255 (оно же -1) прибавить единицу, то в этой ячейке памяти будет 0. но вот соседние ячейки останутся нетронутыми или одна из них (+1/-1 по адресу) увеличится на 1?
нужно ли писать проверку на !=255 для правильной работы?
и аналогично для вычитания из 0, изменится ли содержимое одной из соседних ячеек памяти?

и сразу же: проверка i!=255, i!=-1 или (i>>7) != 0 сработает быстрее?

Comment: Не будет, конечно. Переменные во всех языках изолированы друг от друга.

Comment: По поводу проверок, компилятор умеет нанооптимизации лучше вас, поверьте. Пишите как понятнее, не экономьте.

Comment: @VladD надоело, наверняка, Вам на глупые вопросы отвечать. благодарю за ответы. в прошлой теме осталась ещё одна "загадка" в комментарии к Вашему ответу. было бы приятно узнать Ваше мнение.

Comment: этого не нужно делать даже в ASM, и изоляция переменных тут в общем то ни причем. Просто существуют отдельные инструкции процессора, для работы с данными длиной 8, 16, 32 и 64 бита. Компилятор (JIT) просто выбирает наиболее подходящие инструкции при формировании двоичного кода.

Comment: @rdorn <шутка>на сколько баллов от 0 до пингвина вы оцениваете мои вопросы на фоне бессонницы?</шутка>. Благодарю за развёрнутый ответ, это именно то, что я хотел знать.

Comment: на фоне нынешнего среднего уровня образования в области базовой теории вычислительной техники, к сожалению, ваши вопросы вполне логичны. Ни кто не хочет читать скучные книжки про биты, байты и прочую "низкоуровневую ересь" - отсюда и вопросы.

Comment: @rdorn "интересные факты обо мне". если плевать, то не читать: а у меня ведь 5 лет по направлению "программная инженерия". но вот это никто не объяснял, просто сиди и пиши решение выданной задачи в студии всё время. линукс (на парах) посмотрели только на 5 курсе. одногруппники тупые как пробки, а гугл не помог. когда не спится, ищу ответы в интернете на волнующие темы.

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин: Там вроде rdorn правильно сказал. Если в языке нет возможности создавать новые операторы, то их туда никак не добавить.

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин под образованием я имею ввиду всех участников процесса, хороших преподавателей тоже не так чтобы много. Хотя от личного желания тоже многое зависит. Но это уже совсем офтоп пошел.

Comment: Так в С++ или в С#? Вы уверены, что спецификации этих языков одинаковы в этом отношении? В языке С++ переполнение знаковых целых типов приводит к *неопределенному поведению*.

Comment: @AnT я не говорил, что они одинаковы. Если у Вас есть желание рассказать о своих знаниях по этому поводу, то я с удовольствием прочитаю. Другие товарищи меня уверили, что в любом яп высокого уровня переменные изолированы друг от друга. Именно переменные, а не указатели на участки памяти. Через указатели в C++ наверняка можно выстрелить себе в ногу.

Comment: @Василий Пупкин: Ваш вопрос задан слишком общо, но при этом содержит странные чересчур конкретные постулаты, типа "255 (оно же -1)" и "в этой ячейке памяти будет 0". Уточните вопрос: о каким именно типах и каком именно переполнении идет речь? В С++ знаковые переполнения и беззнаковые переполнения ведут себя сильно по-разному.

Comment: @AnT в памяти будет лежать FF, если его выводить на экран как __int8, то будет -1, если выводить как unsigned __int8, то будет 255, я так понимаю. Но если Вы говорите, что они ведут себя по-разному, значит соседний байт пострадает в одном случае, а из -1 просто будет 0 во втором

Comment: @Василий Пупкин: Они ведут себя по разному на уровне языка С++. Если вы инкрементируете `uint8_t a = 255`, то обязательно должно получиться 0. Если вы инкрементируете `int8_t a = 127`, то компилятор может просто вообще отказаться генерировать код, ибо поведение не определено.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если кратко и не вдаваясь в подробности архитектур конкретных процессоров, то ситуация следующая:

1. Процессор поддерживает работу со словами разной длины: 1, 2, 4, 8 байт, возможно следующие поколения будут поддерживать более длинные слова.
2. Для каждого размера слов существуют отдельные аппаратные инструкции.
3. Типы данных в языках более высокого уровня, чем двоичный код, учитывают допустимые размеры слов.
4. Все операции выполняются процессором в собственной специальной памяти (обычно регистрах). Данные из оперативной памяти читаются в регистры, над ними производятся действия, результат кладется обратно.

Таким образом ни какого способа повредить данные соседней ячейки памяти при операциях сдвига или арифметических операциях с переполнением просто не существует.

Ну и по поводу проверок и оптимизаций. **@VladD** абсолютно верно заметил, что современные компиляторы умеют отлично оптимизировать код, поэтому писать надо так, чтобы код был понятен человеку. Кроме того понятный код и компилятору будет гораздо легче оптимизировать.

Comment: ещё один вопрос на эту тему: действительно ли выделяется 1 байт, если использовать класс Int8 (он же byte) или в любом случае для х64 приложения будет выделено минимум 8 байт? или ещё вариант: компилятор сам соберёт таких "однобайтников" (в качестве полей одного класса) в структуру размером 8 байт (Int64, long)?

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин с выделением памяти сложнее, ее может быть выделено больше чем реально нужно, или может быть произведена упаковка отдельных байт в слово для выравнивания при адресации, но при вычислениях используется ровно один байт, независимо от размещения в памяти.

Comment: "Архитектуры процессоров" тут совершенно ни при чем, ибо вопрос был о языках С++ и C#, а не о машинных инструкциях. Решения о том, что произойдет в случае возникновения такого переполнения, принимаются в первую очередь на уровне языка. И это не теоретизирование, а вполне реальное практическое соображение, выливающееся в современных компиляторах в реализацию напр. *strict overflow semantics*. Если код С++ программы допускает знаковое переполнение, то эффект такого переполнения запросто может вылезти за пределы исходного целочисленного типа, ибо поведение не определено.

Comment: @AnT В результате переполнения произойдет выброс соответствующего флага процессора. Все. А вот что делать с этим флагом уже принимают решение разработчики языка.

Comment: @rdorn: Абсолютно неверно. Компиляторы С и С++ имеют право генерировать код опираясь на аксиому того, что знаковые переполнения *никогда не происходят* (ибо в противном случае поведение все равно не определено). Это называется *strict overflow semantics*. В таком коде может и не быть никакого "выброса соответствующего флага процессора" просто потому, что самого переполняющего кода не будет сгенерировано вообще - компилятор, распознав его как таковой, либо выбросит его нафиг, либо исказит до неузнаваемости.

Comment: @AnT ок. все верно, но в вопрос был о возможности повредить соседние данные в памяти.

Comment: @rdorn: Во-первых, при возникновении неопределенного поведения возможно *все*. Во-вторых, фокусирование именно на "памяти" тут вряд ли уместно. В ситуациях с UB, меня совсем не удивит повреждение значения соседней переменной, когда две переменные оказались соседями в разных частях одного регистра процессора.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61795/discussion-between-rdorn-and-ant).

Answer (score 3):

Ситуации когда число может выйти за предел в операциях, контролируется опциями компилятора. Адресное пространство устроено так, что арифметические опрерации не могут выйти за рамки отведённой области никак, но из-за переполнения результат операции будет некорректным (или неполным).

В с# проверка иногда включена для "более устойчивого кода" (согласно спецификации она отключена). Для отключения этой проверки используется `unchecked`. Для включения проверки используется `checked`.

```
 byte a; a=255; a++; // Получите исключение
 byte b; b=255; unchecked{ b++; };   b = unchecked( b-1); // Исключения не будет.
 checked { byte c; c=255; c++; }; // Получите исключение всегда
```

В с++ чуть сложнее, нужно смотреть опции компилятора. По умолчанию как правило проверок нету, в случае переполнения результат получится не тот который ожидался. У некоторых компиляторов есть проверка на overflow (в delphi {$O+} в с++ в некоторых версиях `#pragma options +o`). Флаги проверяются сложно. Проще всего по результату операции понять что произошло переполнение, чуть сложнее - с помощью `__emit__` или `__asm` проверять cf и of на ассемблере (работает быстрее). Например `__asm { sbb eax,eax; mov f_cf, eax; }` или `__emit__(0x1B,0xC0); f_cf=_EAX;` (для borland).

Comment: Нуууу... По умолчанию установлен unchecked-контекст. http://ideone.com/uyiur0

Comment: @VladD, а VS с тобой согласна?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Не знаю, я с телефона, но не думаю, что Mono настолько не выполняет спецификацию.

Comment: @Vlad сейчас посмотрю что скажет VS, в ASP.NET она вроде включена, а в application незнаю.

Comment: @VladD, по спецификации по умолчанию unchecked. Но у меня есть подозрение, что в параметрах solution'а где-то зарыт флаг, чтоб сделать checked :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Насчёт solution'а не уверен, т. к. это должно быть тогда автоматически вкомпилировано в уже скомпилированные библиотеки (и возможно повалит их код). Вот в настройки _проекта_ как-то больше верится.

Comment: @VladD, ну да, я проект и имел в виду. А на скомпилированные это вообще не распространяется - у них же уже всё в il-коде.